# How to navigate to a new screen on a button click in SAP Advanced Workflow

Tags: groovy, workflow, sap-business-technology-platform

I'm new to SAP Advanced Workflow. I'm developing an application in which I have created a form using the form designer. In that form there needs to be a button on the click of which it should load a new screen with another form. For several days, I'm researching on ways how to do that but not able to find out a convincing way for it. I have created a workflow for my application and designed the form in the create case step of that form. Now where I have to build the second form and how that can be linked with the existing one on a button click? Can anyone please help?

Comment: Again, I have retagged your question to use [tag:sap-business-technology-platform], because [tag:sap] should not be used because it's the company name, it's ambiguous (see the tag guidance). Workflow is part of many SAP software. I hope you understand. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

You can design a form using sections in the same create case form and hide the sections accordingly based on click events.
For example, section1 will have your initial form/elements with the submit button and section2 with next form/elements which should display after click of submit button.
To make them functional, hide the section2 in the before showing form script of create case and in the form event script of submit button, hide the section1 and show the section2.